# when added spin (spin.js) - web page lose functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, I need help about spin function (using `spin.min.js` script)

Problem appears when I added it to my web page, web page loge functionality - I can not click on any link and can not mark anything with mouse. I don't know what's the problem, please help me.

SCRIPT IN BODY TAG

```
<script src="js/vendor/spin.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="loading loading-out">
    <div id="spin">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.loading{
background: #F7F7F7;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 500;


.loading-out{
-webkit-opacity: 0;
-moz-opacity: 0;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;


#spin{
margin: 0px auto;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
```

JQUERY

```
$(function()

    $(window).load(function() {
        // Fadeout loading
        $('.loading').addClass('loading-out');

        // Hide loading
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.loading').hide();
        }, 800);
    });
```

Comment: check the console log, any error? have u put the correct order for ur script?(jquery need to be at top most)

Answer (score 0):

1. Your CSS definitions must be enclosed in `{}`. Right now it's only `{` without closing `}`
2. Your jQuery anonymous function is missing `{}`. Change `$(function() /* window load */` to `$(function() {/* window load */})`.

Check dev tools console to see if there is any errors. It may also be that your JS is taking huge amount of memory and browser is still executing JS while you try to interact with it.
Check if you have jQuery loaded before any script that uses `$`.